# Are static fields or properties initialized once?

Tags: c#, properties, static, initialization, field

With the code below, will each call to Test.someBaseField or Test.someBaseProperty result in the function being called and a new instance of SomeBase being created? or does that only happen once at the start?

How would I set it up for the latter (called once at the start)?

```
public class SomeBase {}
public class SomeObjectA : SomeBase {}
public class SomeObjectB : SomeBase {}

public class Test
{
    public static bool someBool = true;

    public static SomeBase someBaseField = GetBase(someBool);
    public static SomeBase someBaseProperty { get { return GetBase(someBool); } }

    public static SomeBase GetBase(bool getA)
    {
        if(getA)
            return new SomeObjectA() as SomeBase;       
        else
            return new SomeObjectB() as SomeBase;
    }
}
```

Comment: The field is initialized once. The property getter is executed on each access, so GetBase will be called each time. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758.aspx)'s a reference.

Comment: if I have a property in another class referencing Test.someBaseProperty, that will be set dynamically at every call correct? while if I have a field that references Test.someBaseProperty it'll be set only once with its initial value correct? Thanks again!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3):

Get base will be called each time for either property and a new instance of somebase will be returned every time. What you have going on there is called a factory.

What you are wanting to do is create a singleton. There are many methods to create singletons but the most popular is to track some field or property and return that every time if initialized or initialize it if not.

so you are looking at doing something like:

```
static someBase _trackingVar;
public static someBase someProperty{ 
    get
    {
        if(_trackingVar == null){
            _trackingVar = GetBase(...);
        }
        return _trackingVar;
    }
}
```

The one problem with this approach is that it is not thread safe. There's a thread safe version of this approach to singleton creation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx for more details

Answer (score 1):

Each call to "new" would create a new instance of the class "SomeBase". So in your case, these two lines would create two new instances .

```
public static SomeBase someBaseField = GetBase(someBool);
public static SomeBase someBaseProperty { get { return GetBase(someBool); } }
```

Please note that, in both the cases , you are only making the references as static. static references have no impact on object creation.

If you want to create a single object only,
use  a private filed :

```
private static SomeBase _someBaseField = null;
```

Add a null check in GetBase() like following :

```
if (_someBaseField == null)
{
    _someBaseField = new SomeObjectA() as SomeBase; 
    return _someBaseField;
}
else 
{
    return _someBaseField;
}
```

optionally you can change the someBaseProperty, so that you can use the property setter internally too.

```
public static SomeBase someBaseProperty 
{
    get { return GetBase(someBool); }
    private set(value) { _someBaseField = value; }
}
```

There is no need to expose the Filed as a public.

Comment: `someBaseProperty` calls `GetBase`, so now you've created mutual infinite recursion.. except that `someBaseProperty` has no setter, so it won't compile :P

Comment: what do you mean by "mutual infinite recursion"? I don't think its going to create recursion. yes, the setter  has to be there for someBaseProperty.

Comment: The code you added to `GetBase()` calls the `someBaseProperty` getter. The `someBaseProperty` getter calls `GetBase()`.